# Why dont the Command Button excecute the form

Tags: vb.net-2010

Good day. I Created a form that worked perfectlt, after testing the Command Button a few times and entering information into the form I decided to straiten out the form and make it tidy. after saving the form i tried to click the Command butten but this time it gave me a Error 424. Object Required. 
(I tried to upload pictures with no success)

When I Check the Debug it highlight the `.show` command.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ClaimUserForm.Show
End Sub
```

I also tried:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Claim as ClaimUserForm
    Set Claim = new ClaimUser
    claim.show
End Sub
```

But the debug re-appear.

in the form property window the form name is ClaimUserForm

Please help, I cant understand why it suddenly gave this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is your button working properly? It seems it's missing the sender-object and the events.

Also `set` is not necessary.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CommandButton1.Click
    Dim Claim As ClaimUserForm = New ClaimUser
    Claim.Show
End Sub
```

`sender As Object, e As EventArgs` and `Handles Button1.Click` are missing.